# Generate a flat file using Apex

Tags: apex

I would like to generate a text file with a list of products containing the standard information like Product Code, Product Name etc. Initially my idea was to create a report and then export it as a .csv file and then use a third party app to generate the flat file but we would like to generate it within Salesforce. Any ideas related to this is very much appreciated.

The closest thread I was able to find in the community is here (https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000091BhIAI) but it is not that clear.

Below is my code

It pulls different fields from Opp Line Items and the spaces that you're seeing are intentional. I would like to add 151 spaces immediately after the Billing_Amount field so I used RPAD which I don't think is the right one to use. Also at the end of letter "Z", I want to break this line and repeat it for another Product (from 010AE....... till Z).

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" extensions="GenerateTextFile" contentType="text/tab-separated-values#TextFile.txt"  >

<apex:repeat value="{!GenerateTextFile}" var="OLI">

010AE   RR      GGGG       {!OLI.ProductCode}                                                                                                                     RPAD('{!OLI.Billing_Amount__c}',151,' ')00000001                                             Z

</apex:repeat>

</apex:page>
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? What are the details of your flat file format, and what aspect of it are you struggling with? Please [edit] to add information rather than posting comments.

Comment: Thanks for your response David. I've updated my question and please let me know if you need any additional info.